# Why won't my goods sell?

Tags: farmville-country-escape

So I used to be able to sell my goods in the market almost as fast as I could post them. But as of recently, they've stopped selling. I'm selling the same products as before and the products that seem to be selling (based on "sold out" signs in the marketplace) and at the same prices as everyone else if not lower! What gives!?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the market is a bit luck-of-the-draw.  There's a lot of things that could be a factor, but there's really nothing you can do to change any of them.

It could be that the people who are matched up with you don't want what you're selling.  There are a lot of goods that I just don't buy unless Eddie wants me to sell him an obscene quantity of.  (Baked Potatoes and Goat Milk, for instance)

It could be that there are a lot of other people selling the same good.  While you might think price matters in this case, often times I find myself just buying goods from whoever is first on the list, since time is something of a factor in market buying transactions.

I myself tend to sell the same items over and over again, at the same default price.  I also tend to see wide swings in terms of how long it takes for the items to sell.  I might put up 2 sets of 2 peaches, and one sells immediately while the other lingers for *hours*.  They're the same item, sold at the same price, by the same seller, and the market sale time varies significantly.

There's only a couple of things that have much of an effect:

- Bad network connection.  If you can't connect to the Country Escape servers, sometimes your goods don't make it to the big market in the sky.  If you can view other people's stuff, though, chances are this isn't an issue.
- Being in an active co-op.  You can always see your co-op's stuff for sale, so things tend to sell a bit quicker owing to this larger group of people with constant access to your market.

Beyond that, you're just kind of stuck with whatever the market does for you...